# RegEx for a 6 character long string that consists of four letters followed by 2 numbers

Tags: regex

I am able to get individual RegEx for each of the following conditions:

- string is *6* characters long
- first *4* characters are *letters a-z*
- last *2* characters are *numbers*

How do I create a RegEx that creates a match when ALL of these conditions are met?

For example, a valid match would be `xqwl82`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could this regex

```
^[a-z]{4}\d{2}$
```

If you need uppercase letters too

```
^[A-Za-z]{4}\d{2}$
```

or with case insentive flag

```
^[A-Z]{4}\d{2}$
```

1. ^ Beginning of string
2. $ end of string
3. [a-z]{4} Matches 4 letters
4. \d{2} Matches 2 numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-z]{4}\d{2}$
```

- Surround everything with `^$` so it will match the string exactly
- `[x-y]` creates a character set with all characters from `x` to `y`
- `\d` matches a digit. If your regex engine doesn't support it, you can use `[0-9]` instead
- `x{n}` says `x` will be repeated `n` times

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/sX4pX7/1)

Comment: What if there are Uppercases?

Comment: Then you can add `A-Z` to be character set. But OPs question didn't ask that.

Comment: I upvoted you but it could be helpful if future people are searching for that to edit and add this possibility

Answer (score 0):

The correct regex is:

[a-z]{4}[0-9]{2}

The first four characters {4} have to be a-z [a-z]. The last two {2} have to be digits between 0 and 9 [0-9]

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-z]{4}[0-9]{2}$
```

should do. Explanation:

```
^ is beginning of string
[a-z]{4} four occurrences of one character in "a" to "z"
[0-9]{2} the same
$ end of string
```